# subir archivo a servidor y guardar ruta en BD con ASP Core 3.1

Tags: c#, imagen, asp.net-core, asp

Quisiera seleccionar un fichero a través de una aplicación WEB y guardar el fichero en `wwwroot\image` y el nombre del fichero en la base de datos.

El código que utilizo es el siguiente para intentar recuperar el nombre y la ruta del fichero:

**Modelo**:

```
    public partial class Infraestructura
    {        
        public Infraestructura()
        {
            Adquisicion = new HashSet<Adquisicion>();
        }        

        [Key]
        public decimal  ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        //StringLength significa Min. y max. Longitud de caracteres permitidos en un campo de datos
        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Introduzca el código de la infraestructura")]
        [Display(Name = "Código")]
        public string CODIGO_INFRAESTRUCTURA { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Introduzca la denominación de la infraestructura")]
        //MaxLength significa Max. longitud de matriz o datos de cadena permitidos
        [MaxLength(75, ErrorMessage = "Este campo no pueder exceder de 75 caracteres")]
        [Display(Name = "Denominación")]
        public string DENOMINACION { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Introduzca el año de inventario")]
        [Range(2000, 2050, ErrorMessage = "Introduzca un valor entre 2000 y 2050")]
        [Display(Name = "Año inventario")]
        public short ANOINVENTARIO { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Fotografía")]                
        public string RUTA_FOTO_PORTADA { get; set; }
       
        //Resto de campos
        [Display(Name = "Tipo infraestructura")]
        public int? TipoInfraestructura { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Sistema de coordenadas")]
        public string SistemaCoordenadas { get; set; }

        public IFormFile FileUpload { get; set; }
}
```

**Vista**:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />
            <div class="form-group">

                <dl>
                    <dt>
                        <label asp-for="FileUpload"></label>
                    </dt>
                    <dd>
                        <input asp-for="FileUpload" type="file">
                        <span asp-validation-for="FileUpload"></span>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
                <input asp-page-handler="Upload" class="btn" type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </div>
            <input asp-for="RUTA_FOTO_PORTADA" class="form-control" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CODIGO_INFRAESTRUCTURA" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CODIGO_INFRAESTRUCTURA" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CODIGO_INFRAESTRUCTURA" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="DENOMINACION" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="DENOMINACION" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="DENOMINACION" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ANOINVENTARIO" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ANOINVENTARIO" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ANOINVENTARIO" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TipoInfraestructura" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="TipoInfraestructura" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.infraestructuratipo,"Codigo","Descripcion"))"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="TipoInfraestructura" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="SistemaCoordenadas" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="SistemaCoordenadas" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.sistemascoordenadas,"Codigo","Descripcion"))"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="SistemaCoordenadas" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
</div>
```

**Controlador**:

```
// POST: Infraestructuras/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(decimal  id, [Bind("ID,CODIGO_INFRAESTRUCTURA,DENOMINACION,ANOINVENTARIO,RUTA_FOTO_PORTADA,TipoInfraestructura,SistemaCoordenadas")] Infraestructura infraestructura)
        {
            if (id != infraestructura.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    var a = infraestructura.FileUpload;
                    _context.Update(infraestructura);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!InfraestructuraExists(infraestructura.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(infraestructura);
        }
```

El caso es que `var a = infraestructura.FileUpload;` siempre es nulo **¿como se podría hacer?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola yo acabo de hacer algo parecido he hice esto:

**Modelo**

```
public class VideoModel{
   public System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper VideoFile { get; set; }
}
```

**Vista**

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.VideoFile, new { type = "file", accept = "video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VideoFile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
```

**Controlador**

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
     string RutaGuardado = SaveVideo(model.VideoFile);
}
```

Metodo para guardarlo en una carpeta en el servidor

```
    private string SaveVideo(System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper file) {
        
        //Ruta donde lo vas a guardar
        var uploadFilesDir = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Videos");
        var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(uploadFilesDir, file.FileName);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileSavePath)) {
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileSavePath);
        }

        // Save the uploaded file to "UploadedFiles" folder
        file.SaveAs(fileSavePath);
        return fileSavePath;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que uses un Custom ModelBinder, y que envíes por separado el archivo de los datos del formulario, yo lo haría de esta manera.

```
public Task CustomModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    if (bindingContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
    }

    // Check the value sent in
    var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
    {
        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

        // Attempt to convert the input value
        var valueAsString = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;
        var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(valueAsString, bindingContext.ModelType);
        if (result != null)
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

El controlador basta con que llames el método para subir el archivo y realices tu lógica de negocios, luego guardas la ruta que te devuelve el metodo Upload:

```
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put(int id,
        [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(JsonModelBinder))] Infraestructura model
        , IList<IFormFile> files)
    {
        if (model == null) return BadRequest();
        //Traer la entidad que deseas modificar
        var filesPath = await _fileService.Upload(files,"NombreDelArchivo");
        Entidad.RUTA_FOTO_PORTADA = filesPath;
        //Logia de negocio
        //Guardar datos
        return Ok();
    }
```

Método para subir archivo, el cual recibe una lista de File, pero igual te va bien con lo que tratas de hacer:

```
public async Task<string> Upload(IList<IFormFile> files, string name)
{
        var filesPath = string.Empty;
        if (files.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var formFile in files)
            {
                if (formFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(@$"{RootDirectory}\{name}{MediaType}");
                    filesPath += filePath + ";";

                    await using var stream = File.Create(filePath);
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }

            filesPath = filesPath.Remove((filesPath.Length-1));
        }

        return filesPath;
    }
```