# ¿Cómo enviar una imagen al controlador en MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc, model-view-controller

Buenas estoy usando la versión asp.net 3.1 y necesito pasar una imagen al controlador para luego cambiar el formato de la misma o redimensionarla y volverla a enviar a la vista para que se descargue en el ordenador del usuario con el nuevo formato(.jpg, .png...) y la nueva resolucion.
Este el codigo html de la vista:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="file" id="imageFile" name="imageFile" />
    <br />
    <label>New width:</label>
    <input type="text" name="widthText"/>
    <br/>
    <label>New format:</label>
    <select>
        <option id=".jpg">.jpg</option>
        <option id=".png">.png</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="sendIt" name="sendIt" value="Send" />
</form>
```

He visto que por ejemplo se puede usar ajax, pero nunca lo he usado y no entiendo bien la sintaxis.
Tambien he visto lo de crear un ViewModel, pero no me quedó muy claro que datos tengo que pasarle, soy nuevo en esto del MVC.

edit: Se me olvidó comentar que tengo que realizar esta operación en memoria.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/383662/324) no te sirve?

Comment: @gbianchi no, yo no quiero bases de datos para nada

Comment: Y? el resto de la respuesta hace lo que vos queres.. o no?

Comment: @gbianchi no, la versión del MVC de esa respuesta no me sirve